# Где должен быть title страницы, если она формируется из трех шаблонов?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap, mvc

Сделал для тренировки MVC сайт на PHP. Как водится, у меня в папке View есть шаблон header.php, который цепляется сверху к главной странице и любой записи. Также есть footer.php. Есть шаблон тела записи pageBody.php. Как нужно записать title description и keywords для страницы, чтобы это правильно понимали поисковики и браузер... В каждом из трех шаблонов, участвующих в формировании каждой записи есть свои  и . Куда же все писать? В  pageBody? вот пример записи: http://f90577wq.beget.tech/%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BC

Галвная страница даже не формирует сниппет в месенджерах, хотя title, description и keywords у нее имеются... http://f90577wq.beget.tech/

Comment: Это какой-то кадавр, а не "MVC сайт". Почему у вас теги head в каждом шаблоне? Сделайте нормальный шаблон сначала, а потом уже теги выводите. Где положено - в блоке head.

Comment: @Ипатьев то есть в норме теги <head></head> должны быть только в header.php папки View?

Comment: Мне кажется, перед тем как делать сайт на РНР, вам надо сначала подучить HTML. просто потому, что результатом работы РНР является именно HTML. И если вы не знаете, что хотите получить (какой HTML), то любой РНР код писать бессмысленно. Ну разумеется теги <head></head> пишутся в самом верху документа HTML! Вам надо сначала сделать HTML для своего сайта, а потом уже разбивать его на кусочки, которые будет выводить РНР

Comment: @Ипатьев Дело в том, что каждый файл html должен вот так строиться, как я понял: <html><head></head><body></body></html>. С книге по html так и написано, выходит, если мой html формируется из трех кусков, то <head></head> нужен только верхнему шаблону header.php, а в остальных файлах будет <html><body></body></html>, но мне не доводилось видеть документов с такой структурой.... Даже в Wordpress работал там в любом документе есть и то, и то...

Comment: Еще раз. У вас только ОДИН документ HTML. Тот, который получается в итоге. Остальное - это просто кусочки, на которые он разбит, и потом собирается обратно. Неужели это так трудно понять? Вам надо забыть про РНР, и сесть учить HTML. И сделать нормальный HTML для своего сайта. А не вот это вот убожество, которое выводится сейчас

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!